Swiper JS custom style transformations on init
I have a reviews swiper which appears like a deck of cards for which I need custom transformations.

I am using following code, the styles are being calculated properly but they do not get applied to the swiper slides.
const reviewSwiper = new Swiper('.reviews-swiper', {
slidesPerView: 1,
spaceBetween: 0,
oneWayMovement: true,
rewind: true,
on: {
    init: function(s) {
        let rotate = -8;
        const width = s.slides[0].clientWidth;
        s.slides.forEach((slide, i) => {
            slide.style.transform = `translate3d(calc(${-width*i}px), calc(0px), calc(0px)) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(${rotate}deg) scale(1);`;
            console.log(slide.style.transform);
            rotate += 8;
        });
    }
}

});

Could you make demo od CodePen?
